# How to stop nvidia-settings creating new xorg.conf?

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia, display-server

I've searched many times for an answer but have NEVER found a good and proper answer that fixes this annoying problem when using Nvidia drivers for Linux.

Everytime I reboot the system, nvidia-settings creates a NEW xorg.conf file, backing up my own configuration settings in the process. What I want is to STOP nvidia-settings from doing this and just READ my xorg.conf configuration file.

On every reboot I have my `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11/` -> reboot system `/etc/X11/` then has `xorg.conf` <- nvidia-settings replacement, my xorg.conf backed up to be like this -> `xorg.conf.4023473`. Everytime I have to go into `/etc/X11/` directory to delete the one nvidia-settings created and put my one back as the main one again before logging.

Previous unsatisfactory answers I've come across are people saying edit nvidia-settings to `read-only`, but don't explain to edit what exactly. Edit the binary executable which is just garbled junk? add a parameter to the executable or what? I need answers to this.

I just need `nvidia-settings` to just `read-config` not create a new one of it's own accord. Changing the read-write permissions for Xorg.conf doesn't work because nvidia-settings runtime level is system level and can override permissions. I have no idea how many times this questions been asked, but a proper detailed satisfactory answer has never been posted before.

Comment: Which distribution are you using? At least on Arch I've never seen nvidia-settings touch Xorg.conf on reboot.

Comment: with Linux Mint distribution version 18.1 (based on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial)